# Is there no way to view rendered HTML from github wiki (of a private repo)

Tags: css, github, markdown, render, wiki

Is there no way to view rendered HTML from github wiki (of a private repo) via markdown ....and what if the files are also stored in wiki section of the repo?

I've been trying to figure a way out. Maybe its not working because its in a private repo?

I do include the Token in the URL.... I dont get it!

I tried out these sites and the first one worked but unfortunately didn't render CSS. SO CLOSE! http://htmlpreview.github.com

I post a link that works in a tab here https://rawgit.com/

Then it generates 2 URL's, both of which go to a 404 page.

Plane old out of luck?

Comment: You could Check If GitHub Pages ist available for private repos.